# Oozie error - while importing data from mysql to hdfs

Tags: sqoop, oozie

I am trying to import data to hdfs from mysql through sqoop. I am able to run sqoop through shell and it is working fine . but when I am invoking through oozie. it is arising following error and getting fail. I have also included jars.

**Now I am trying this at my home - CDH 5.3 single node in virtual box but error is still the same**

I know this has been discussed earlier but still no help..

Main error is:

```
ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
```

Job properties file is as below, present in local environment

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8032

oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/harry/
```

Workflow.xml file is as below, which is present in HDFS under ${nameNode}/user/harry/

```
<workflow-app name="Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
<start to="sqoop-c68d"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="sqoop-c68d">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <arg>import</arg>
        <arg> --connect</arg>
        <arg>jdbc:mysql://localhost/oozie_training</arg>
        <arg>--username</arg>
        <arg>root</arg>
        <arg>--password</arg>
        <arg>cloudera</arg>
        <arg>--table</arg>
        <arg>user</arg>
        <arg>--target-dir</arg>
        <arg>/training/sqoop</arg>
        <arg>-m</arg>
        <arg>1</arg>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
<end name="End"/>
```

I have included all the necessary jars under below path

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20141218070949/sqoop
Found 75 items
-rw-r--r--   1 root  oozie     960374 2016-05-26 22:00 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20141218070949/sqoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie oozie      16924 2014-12-18 07:09 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20141218070949/sqoop/oozie-sharelib-sqoop-4.0.0-cdh5.3.0.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie oozie    1010790 2014-12-18 07:09 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20141218070949/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.5-cdh5.3.0.jar
```

I have also restarted the oozie server after adding jars.

Error logs i am getting are as below.

```
2016-05-24 10:37:17,994  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[***]             USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-05-24 10:37:17,997  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2016-05-24 10:37:17,997  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2016-05-24 10:37:18,164  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@:start:
2016-05-24 10:37:18,165  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W
2016-05-24 10:37:18,188  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] Start action [0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-05-24 10:37:26,080  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] Trying to get job [job_1462295072181_0163], attempt [1]
2016-05-24 10:37:26,106  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] checking action, hadoop job ID [job_1462295072181_0163] status [RUNNING]
2016-05-24 10:37:26,108  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] [***0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d***]Action status=RUNNING
2016-05-24 10:37:26,114  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] [***0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d***]Action updated in DB!
2016-05-24 10:37:26,184  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d
2016-05-24 10:37:37,181  INFO CallbackServlet:520 - SERVER[***] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] callback for action [0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d]
2016-05-24 10:37:37,314  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] Trying to get job [job_1462295072181_0163], attempt [1]
2016-05-24 10:37:37,388  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] action completed, external ID [job_1462295072181_0163]
2016-05-24 10:37:37,395  WARN SqoopActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
2016-05-24 10:37:37,484  INFO ActionEndXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2016-05-24 10:37:37,679  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] Start action [0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-05-24 10:37:37,683  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] [***0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@Kill***]Action status=DONE
2016-05-24 10:37:37,683  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Trend_Analysi_Scoop_Script] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] [***0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@Kill***]Action updated in DB!
2016-05-24 10:37:37,930  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@Kill
2016-05-24 10:37:37,931  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W
2016-05-24 10:37:37,931  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[***] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-c68d] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000001-160524103133053-oozie-oozi- W@sqoop-c68d
```

**I think oozie is not picking up the share/lib, if so it would be really great if someone could help me out on the same**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the logs from launcher job? You should find more information there regarding the failure?

Comment: Where i can get a launcher job logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some issue with your "command" tag in the sqoop action. Since it is already a sqoop action "/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/sqoop/bin/sqoop" is not needed.
Refer the examples in the below link to correct them. And try rerunning the job again.

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html#Sqoop_Action

Comment: I have tried the same stuff at my home system and got the same error.

All the suggestions you have said are implemented and edit the question with the same.

Comment: There is another way you can use the sharelibs. Just copy all the jars that you need to a directory on HDFS  like "/user/oozie/libraries" and use the following property in your job.properties file.

oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/libraries

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `--query` option in the `command` element, which is not supported in the oozie. You need to use the `arg` tag and provide all the arguments individually. The `command` tag is split by whitespace so it will not work with `--query` option. Here is the sample example:

```
        <arg>import</arg>
        <arg>--connect</arg>
        <arg>jdbc:mysql://host:3306/oozie</arg>
        <arg>--username</arg>
        <arg>user</arg>
        <arg>--password</arg>
        <arg>pwd</arg>
        <arg>--driver</arg>
        <arg>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</arg>
        <arg>--query</arg>
        <arg>"select BUNDLE_ACTIONS.* from BUNDLE_ACTIONS where $CONDITIONS"</arg>
        <arg>--hcatalog-table</arg>
        <arg>bundle_actions</arg>
        <arg>--hcatalog-database</arg>
        <arg>oozie</arg>
        <arg>--skip-dist-cache</arg>
        <arg>-m</arg>
        <arg>1</arg>
```

Comment: done this but no success yet.. updated question with the same.

Comment: You need to check the launcher job logs. You can access the from the Oozie Web UI. Goto workflow, sqoop action and console URL. This is the launcher job.